# gdb + qt: check variable content

Tags: qt, gdb, pretty-print

ALL,

I'd like to know how do I check the content of the QString under gdb?

If I have a code

```
QString temp = "abc";
```

and after executing it I type

```
p temp
```

I see some address in memory and some references to the QString member variables.

So how do I see the value "abc" for the variable temp?

TIA!

P.S.: I'm working on Gentoo Linux with Qt 5. I also prefer not to install any additional packages - just use standard gdb solution.

Comment: @Felix, the question you referenced does not contain any information on how to display QString content inside gdb. Keep in mind - I'm not asking `how to debug the application` I'm asking `how to perform a very specific task in GDB`. I believe it is 2 very different topics. Therefore my question is NOT a duplicate of the referenced one. Please remove. Thank you in advance. And if you don't know how to answer or just didn't check the referenced question - pass it on to another person.

Comment: @eyllanesc, please see the comment above. In no way my question is even remotely related to the one linked. Thank you.